# Is there any Common Way for updating status using c# in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to update the status using single common way in c#.

For now I know about  SetStateRequest but it did not change its status to any of status. **e.g.** If i want to change status to fulfilled for order or canceled for order then it requires FulfillSalesOrderRequest and CancelSalesOrderRequest .Like wise different different class for quote's status and others.

So I want some common way for change status.If is there any solution please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on CRM 2015 Update 1 or later, SetStateRequest has been deprecated in favor of a normal UpdateRequest, as seen on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932124.aspx):

> Before Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update 1, specialized
> messages were required to update certain entity attribute values. Now,
> UpdateRequest can now be used to set these attributes. The following
> table identifies the specialized deprecated message requests and the
> related message attributes that can be updated using UpdateRequest.

With that being said, FulfillSalesOrderRequest (and the corresponding Requests for quotes) have not been deprecated, so you still need to use them going forward. The common reqeust you are looking for does thus not exist.

Comment: Hi henrik, can you suggest me for which entity SetStateRequest  is not working and i have to use other request.

Comment: @chhaya_patel why don't you try it out? Even beats a good documentation when you try things out first hand.

Comment: can you please give me any reference link

Comment: @henrik , I tried this but it gives me this error."This message can not be used to set the state of SalesOrder to Fulfilled.  In order to set state of SalesOrder to Fulfilled, use the FulfillSalesOrderRequest Request message instead."

Comment: @henrik,Please suggest me what to do

Comment: Hi Henrik,Exactly that is my Question that for fulfill i have to use FulfillSalesOrderRequest Request. so I want to know that is there any common request which is used for change all status?

Comment: No. See the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: ohh.. Thank you so much henrik for reply