# CRM 2011 call Ajax gives Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We have CRM on-premise installed on Local Network.
I wanna change `state` and `statusreason` of `salesorder` ( `Order` entity ).
I saw this [link](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/setstate-request-example-using-javascript/).

And I call the function in this way ( change status to `Canceled` and statusreason to `No Money`:

```
var recordGuid = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
setRecordStatus ("salesorder", recordGuid ,"3", "100001");
```

But it gives me 400 Bad Request Error !
Could any one help me on this?

Comment: As a side note: v1.5 of [Jason Lattimer's RESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases) supports CRM 2011. It's a very helpful tool for building OData queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `CancelSalesOrderRequest` [message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.cancelsalesorderrequest.aspx) to achieve this. Javascript SOAP request Code sample can be found in [SDK.SAMPLES.CancelSalesOrderRequest](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mileyja/archive/2011/10/03/cancel-a-sales-order-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-using-net-or-jscript)

`statecode 2 : Canceled` is having only valid associated `statusreason 4 : No Money`

Your code shows `3 : Fulfilled` & `100001 : Complete` combination. Check it.

Update:

The link you are referring works for most of the CRM entities, but it’s meant for straight forward status changes like Active to Inactive. But special entities like `salesorder` needs special messages as this status changes involves other background platform activities like updating child `salesorderdetail` entities.

You can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39443614/7920473) also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I can change state from active to submitted by this way : 
[link](http://crm2011and2013solutions.blogspot.com/2015/10/change-status-using-javascript.html)
@Arun Vinoth
But wanna go from submitted to canceled ( no money ) or go from submitted to fulfilled. 
The above link does not work for these to purpose.

Comment: I saw that and that helped me !
Thanks alot !
Could please take a look at this thread? 
[this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/288298)